# How can I Delete record which have a duplicate values in each date

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi Dear All I have a table which have Duplicate (or you can say that repeating) record in each date.
I just want to delete each duplicate record from each date,
how its happened is due to Cross Join Please Help me Its looks like this..
Suppose Table Named is **PRODUCT** and its column names are like `ID` and `DATE1`

```
ID       DATE1            typ
------------------------------------
100      01-01-2021       A
101      01-01-2021       B
102      01-01-2021       C
100      01-01-2021       A
101      01-01-2021       B
102      01-01-2021       C
100      01-01-2021       A
101      01-01-2021       B
102      01-01-2021       C
```

In above each ID is repeating every time. I just want to delete each id which is duplicate.

```
100      01-01-2021       A
101      01-01-2021       B
102      01-01-2021       C
```

We applied this

```
delete from your_table a
  where a.rowid > (select min(b.rowid)
                   from your_table b
                   where b.id = a.id
                     and b.date1 = a.date1
                  );
```

But results show me like this

```
100      01-01-2021       A
101      01-01-2021       B
102      01-01-2021       B
```

Or some times it shows `C,C,A` or some times `A,A,C` I know there is all data with all possibilities so how can filter just which we just keep table original data how I am working on it is like I have 3 table one have data like

```
100      01-01-2021       A
101      01-01-2021       B
102      01-01-2021       C
100      10-01-2021       B
101      10-01-2021       C
102      10-01-2021       A
100      20-01-2021       C
101      20-01-2021       A
102      20-01-2021       B
```

One table have data like dates

```
01-01-2021
02-01-2021
03-01-2021
04-01-2021
05-01-2021
```

I want all dates till the next start it appeares all date with same data as like

```
100      01-01-2021       A
101      01-01-2021       B
102      01-01-2021       C
100      02-01-2021       A
101      02-01-2021       B
102      02-01-2021       C
100      03-01-2021       A
101      03-01-2021       B
102      03-01-2021       C
---
100      10-01-2021       B
101      10-01-2021       C
102      10-01-2021       A
100      11-01-2021       B
101      11-01-2021       C
102      11-01-2021       A
```

So on so I tried cross join but cross join make each and every rows to make all possibilities so I tried to dell all other dates to be delete that each day get there only ids but know it shows like that how can i get over this please hep me about this regards to all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one option to delete duplicates:

```
delete from your_table a
  where a.rowid > (select min(b.rowid)
                   from your_table b
                   where b.id = a.id
                     and b.date1 = a.date1
                  );
```

---

Regarding comments you posted and new column PLUS a new table: this is what you have (at lest, that's what I understood) (sample date in lines #1 - 17; query begins at line #18):

```
SQL> with
  2  taba (id, date1, col) as
  3    (select 100, date '2021-01-01', 'A' from dual union all
  4     select 101, date '2021-01-01', 'B' from dual union all
  5     select 102, date '2021-01-01', 'C' from dual union all
  6     select 100, date '2021-01-02', 'A' from dual union all
  7     select 101, date '2021-01-02', 'B' from dual union all
  8     select 102, date '2021-01-02', 'C' from dual union all
  9     select 100, date '2021-01-03', 'A' from dual union all
 10     select 101, date '2021-01-03', 'B' from dual union all
 11     select 102, date '2021-01-03', 'C' from dual
 12    ),
 13  tabb (date1) as
 14    (select date '2021-01-01' from dual union all
 15     select date '2021-01-02' from dual union all
 16     select date '2021-01-03' from dual
 17    )
 18  select a.id, a.date1, a.col
 19  from taba a cross join tabb b;

        ID DATE1               C
---------- ------------------- -
       100 01.01.2021 00:00:00 A
       101 01.01.2021 00:00:00 B
       102 01.01.2021 00:00:00 C
       100 02.01.2021 00:00:00 A
       101 02.01.2021 00:00:00 B
       102 02.01.2021 00:00:00 C
       100 03.01.2021 00:00:00 A
       101 03.01.2021 00:00:00 B
       102 03.01.2021 00:00:00 C
       100 01.01.2021 00:00:00 A
       101 01.01.2021 00:00:00 B
<snip>
       101 02.01.2021 00:00:00 B
       102 02.01.2021 00:00:00 C
       100 03.01.2021 00:00:00 A
       101 03.01.2021 00:00:00 B
       102 03.01.2021 00:00:00 C

27 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Why are you cross-joining these tables? Wouldn't inner join do?

```
 18  select a.id, a.date1, a.col
 19  from taba a join tabb b on a.date1 = b.date1;

        ID DATE1               C
---------- ------------------- -
       100 01.01.2021 00:00:00 A
       101 01.01.2021 00:00:00 B
       102 01.01.2021 00:00:00 C
       100 02.01.2021 00:00:00 A
       101 02.01.2021 00:00:00 B
       102 02.01.2021 00:00:00 C
       100 03.01.2021 00:00:00 A
       101 03.01.2021 00:00:00 B
       102 03.01.2021 00:00:00 C

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Or perhaps `SELECT DISTINCT` (in cross join)?

```
 18  select distinct a.id, a.date1, a.col
 19  from taba a cross join tabb;

        ID DATE1               C
---------- ------------------- -
       100 02.01.2021 00:00:00 A
       102 01.01.2021 00:00:00 C
       101 02.01.2021 00:00:00 B
       102 03.01.2021 00:00:00 C
       100 03.01.2021 00:00:00 A
       100 01.01.2021 00:00:00 A
       101 03.01.2021 00:00:00 B
       101 01.01.2021 00:00:00 B
       102 02.01.2021 00:00:00 C

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

After all, it seems that you aren't actually deleting rows from any table(s), but want to restrict number of rows you get as a result of your `select` statement ...

Comment: its deleted @littlefoot but there is one thing more I have one more column which has like this like ids `100` then date `01-01-2021` and then `A` the value of a is different with each mean 100 have **A** than 101 have **B** than 102 have **C** after this delete it changed I just want like that is there any order by will affect

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you meant to say. Maybe you need to include that new column into subquerie's WHERE clause.

Comment: I edited this again please check comment first during typing enter typed please check once  Regards

Comment: I still don't understand ... perhaps you should edit the original question and post what you have and explain what you'd like to get as a result (i.e. which rules lead from *source* to *target*).

Comment: I edited the main Question please Help me about this Best Regards

Comment: I also added some more info into the answer; have a look, please.